Use of "lassen" change intransitive verbs to transitive verbs
The verb lassen sometimes can correspond a intransitive verb to a transitive verb. The "causative" use of lassen. , 16.3.4 A(iv) Hammer German grammar and usage sixth edition.
Hammer German grammar gives the example of the verb fallen.
My questions. How to know which intransitive verbs allows "lassen" to change the verb to an transitive verb?
Is there a list available of such intransitive verbs that take "lassen"?
Or must one look up each individual intransitive verb in a dictionary?

Duden gave the examples of the transitive verbs fallen, laufen, durchfallen. Tried to find other examples in duden dictionary but have struggled to discover some more.

I'm not sure, whether I understand the question correctly. In Ich lasse den Stift fallen I would consider fallen as still intransitive and lassen as the transitive verb involved.

Edited the post had transposed transitive for intransitive.

Der Stift fiel is the intransitive use of the verb fallen. The used of the verb lassen changes the use of the verb fallen transitive according to Hammer German grammar and usage.

It's not in the dictionary because lassen can be used with pretty much any verb.

Can you please quote Hammer’s exact words in the question, and show where he says them (and in which version – Google gives me a PDF of the book, but there is no section 16.3.4 A(iv) in that book, and section 16 is about the subjunctive so not relevant at all)? Fallen does not become transitive with lassen any more than fall becomes transitive with let in English; that is just plain wrong, and I doubt Hammer actually says that. ‘He let the ball fall *a book’ is completely ungrammatical in English, just like ‘Er ließ den Ball *ein Buch fallen’ is in German.

"Can correspond" it says in Hammar and it does says this "causative" use of lassen. I've edited my original post.

"lassen" is the most common way in German to form a causative and corresponds to English "make" and "let". To cite the Wikipedia article:

A language may have one or more different formal mechanisms for expression of causation. For languages with only one, the semantic range is broad.

In German, the meaning of "lassen" ranges from direct causation like in "fallen lassen" to not taking action to prevent something like in "sterben lassen". Because of this, virtually every verb can be combined with "lassen", even though some will sound like you magically made something happen. E.g. "Es regnen lassen" (to make it rain). If the causee is animate, the meaning can be either to allow so. to or to force so.. Which is meant has to be taken from context.
However, "lassen" tends to be used for more indirect causation. "umfallen lassen" (to let sth. fall) is not knocking it over, just as "fallen lassen" is not throwing it to the ground.

Hammer's grammar portrays German from an English perspective. In this particular case, the point is to show that the two languages structure their lexicon differently. English has quite a few verbs that participate in causative alternation. They are rarer in German; the resulting gaps are filled in different ways.
For instance, in the case of drop, lassen is used to form the causative variant.

The ball dropped to the ground.
He dropped the ball to the ground.
Der Ball fiel auf den Boden.
Er ließ den Ball auf den Boden fallen.

However, with sink, German uses two different verbs: strong intransitive sinken, sank, gesunken vs. weak transitive versenken, versenkte, versenkt.

The ship sank.
A torpedo sank the ship.
Das Schiff sank.
Das Torpedo versenkte das Schiff.

Finally, with open, a reflexive variant is used for the noncausative variant.

The door opened.
Someone opened the door.
Die Tür öffnete sich.
Jemand öffnete die Tür.

Unfortunately, as these examples show, there is indeed some learning evolved.

In general, strong verbs have their own causative variant, built by using an "Ablaut": trinken-tränken ("to make drink"), dringen-drängen, saufen-(er-)säufen, schwimmen-schwemmen and so on.

In general, lassen is deliberate action or inaction by a human actor: Er hat das Schiff sinken lassen is perfectly possible, and examples are easy to find with Google.

Worth noting that just a few examples of the “strong intransitive, ablaut transitive/causative” pattern survive in English too: rise/raise, sit/set, lie/lay (and possibly a few more that escape me now).

@reinierpost, extending that, we can also have Schiff versenken lassen.

I would argue that the difference between sinken and versenken is not one of causation, but rather one of aspect.  sinken emphasizes the process of sinking (and is thus intransitive because it's something that an object just does) whereas versenken emphasizes the final state of being at the bottom of a body of water, a mine, a well, a hole in the ground etc. As @bakunin points out, the causative variant of sinken would be senken (without the prefix ver). It is ver which then adds the perfective aspect.
